# Joining data from a table that is identified by another table

Tags: mysql, join

I have been asked to put together a small reporting system at work. We have a database where users commit information, namely a start and a stop time for various events.

The relevant tables of the DB:
[image]

As you can see, an event has a subcategory, and each subcategory belongs to a category.

I have been asked to produce a graph that represents the total amount of time events of a given *category* have occurred in a given date range.

So for example:

```
Category Name | Total time
**************************
Balloons      | 12h
Chalk         | 5.5h
```

I am struggling with getting a sum out of a join statement. As you can see, in order to map the total amounts of time to various categories, I have to first identify which subcategories belong to which categories, then organize the events accordingly.

I admit, I have been dead-set on writing this in one single query instead of writing a stored procedure or create temporary tables. I was convinced I could get it done with only joins, but it does not seem to be the case. *I am completely open to any solution that works*

One requirement; If a given category has *no* events, it should still appear in the results, only with a default value of 0.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    event_categories.name,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
        events.start,
        events.stop) / 60) AS timeLost
FROM
    events
        LEFT JOIN
    event_subcategories ON event_subcategories.id = events.subcategory
        RIGHT JOIN
    event_categories ON event_categories.id = event_subcategories.id
WHERE
    events.date BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2016-12-22'
        AND events.bed = 1
GROUP BY event_categories.id;
```

It *almost* works, producing a list of categories with the associated time lost. Only it doesn't display all of the categories, just the ones with events associated to them.

Comment: Use `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @Barmar I did (on the event_categories table). II tried it on both joins and the result is the same.

Comment: In `LEFT JOIN`, the first table is the master table, and the second table is the child. In `RIGHT JOIN` it's the other way around.

Comment: Hardly anyone ever uses `RIGHT JOIN`, just `LEFT JOIN`. It should then be `FROM event_categories LEFT JOIN event_subcategories ON ... LEFT JOIN events ON ...`

Comment: Mixing both directions is just totally confusing, I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: @Barmar that's where it gets complicated, because joining the subcategories table to the categories table would produce a whole bunch of the same category repeated. There are multiple subcategories in one category. I can't just join the subcategories to the categories.

Comment: I don't see why that's a problem, since each event is only in one subcategory. You don't get repetition because you eventually group everything by category, not subcategory.

Comment: @Barmar holy crud, that was easy. THANKS!

Comment: You're also using the wrong columns in the join between categories and subcategories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you do the joins. The main table should be `event_categories`. Assuming every category has subcategories, you can then use `INNER JOIN` with `event_subcategories`. Finally use `LEFT JOIN` with `events`, since some subcategories might not have any events.

You were also joining `event_categories` and `event_subcategories` on the wrong columns. It should be `event_subcategories.category`, not `event_subcategory.id`.

When you do a `LEFT JOIN`, any conditions on the child table should be in the `ON` clause, not `WHERE`. Because any category with no events will get `NULL` for all the `event` columns, so the conditions will never succeed for those rows and they would get filtered out as if you were doing `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    c.name,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
        e.start,
        e.stop) / 60) AS timeLost
FROM event_categories AS c
JOIN event_subcategories AS s ON s.category = c.id
LEFT JOIN events AS e ON e.subcategory = s.id 
    AND e.date BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2016-12-22'
    AND e.bed = 1
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Comment: Ok I tried that and it works, but when I add `WHERE
    events.date BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2016-12-22'
        AND events.bed = 1` It doesn't display the categories with no events...

Comment: So basically I need your query to be able to narrow down to a specific date range, and the dates are in the events table.

Comment: Any conditions on the `LEFT JOIN` table need to be put in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Ahhhhh, the problem was that I didn't know you could put conditions on a join like that. Thank you VERY VERY much!!!